# MessagePack and Immutable Objects

Tags: java, msgpack, messagepack

I have many immutable domain objects with private final fields and public getter methods.  Is it possible to serialize them using the [MessagePack implementation for Java](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java)?

I know the `@Message` annotation only supports public fields, but I was hoping to use the `@MessagePackBeans` and `@OrdinalEnum` annotations.  When I try and serialize one of my objects, I don't get any exception on the `.write` call, but serialization fails.  I've included a complete example below.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or should I give up on trying to use MessagePack?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.msgpack.MessagePack;
import org.msgpack.annotation.MessagePackBeans;
import org.msgpack.annotation.OrdinalEnum;

public class MsgPackTest {

  @OrdinalEnum
  public static enum MyEnum {
    A;
  }

  @MessagePackBeans
  public final static class MyObject {
    private final String myString;
    private final MyEnum myEnum;

    public MyObject(String myString, MyEnum myEnum) {
      this.myString = myString;
      this.myEnum = myEnum;
    }
    public String getMyString() {
      return myString;
    }       
    public MyEnum getMyEnum() {
      return myEnum;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final MyObject obj = new MyObject("abc", MyEnum.A);
    final MessagePack msgPack = new MessagePack();
    try {
      final byte[] bytes = msgPack.write(obj); //bytes = [-112]
      MyObject result = msgPack.read(bytes, MyObject.class);
      //Unreachable code - MessageTypeException thrown
      System.out.println("Success: " + result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does serialization fail?  You say up top that no exception happens, but your code says exceptions do happen?  I have little experience with MessagePack, more with ProtoBuf.  I prefer protobuf.

Comment: There is no exception on the `.write` call, but since it doesn't produce a valid byte array, I get an exception on the `.read` call.

Comment: Does it produce an incorrect byte array then, or just null or empty byte array?

Comment: Produces the value in my comment: one byte